# Twitter Image Not Appearing in Tweet from WordPress Website

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, twitter

I’m creating a WordPress plugin where I’m adding a click to Tweet feature for a quote. Below is example HTML code from
http://www.msblogs.mattjennings.net/2018/05/21/another-example-quote/

```html
<a style="text-decoration: none;" onclick="window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=You%20must%20be%20the%20change%20that%20you%20wish%20to%20see%20in%20the%20world.%20%23gandi%20http://www.msblogs.mattjennings.net/2018/05/21/another-example-quote', '_blank', 'width=500,height=500'); return false;" href="#">
  <blockquote>
    <span class="dashicons dashicons-format-quote" style="color: #1da1f2; font-size: 45px; padding-right: 65px; display: block; float: left; height: 50px;"></span>
    <p style="display: inline; padding-top: 10px; font-size: 25px; font-style: normal; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);" onmouseover="this.style.color='#1da1f2'" onmouseout="this.style.color='#000'">You must be the change that you wish to see in the world.</p>
    <p style="color: #1da1f2; font-style: normal; padding-left: 65px;"><i class="dashicons dashicons-twitter" style="color: #1da1f2; font-size: 25px; display: block; float: left; padding-right: 30px;"></i>Click to Tweet</p>   
  </blockquote>
</a>
```

On that same page I also have a `<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://www.msblogs.mattjennings.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/gandi-quote.png" />` tag.

However, when I click the "Click to Tweet" link on that page and Tweet the text the photo in the `<meta name="twitter:image" ... />` tag doesn't appear in the Tweet:
https://twitter.com/iluvmibanh/status/998709839936217088

How can I get this image to appear in the Tweet?

Comment: It looks like this is working - the image (Twitter card) appears in the Tweet. It will not show in the post Tweet popup, it will only show after the Tweet has been posted.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that it can take a number of hours for the photo (taken from a `<meta name="twitter:image" ... />` tag) appear with a Tweet. Thank you.